# Using case_when() to assign two new columns, instead of one

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this sample data:

```
df <- tibble(
  "City1" = c("New York", "Boston", "Chicago"),
  "City2" = c("Chicago", "Cleveland", "Atlanta"))
```

Assume `City1` is the starting point, and `City2` is the destination. I.e., a person traveled from New York to Chicago.

I want to add a column for the starting latitude and a column for starting longitude, and also do the same for the destination city. In all, I want four new columns. I already have the coordinates.

How can I assign the coordinates? I have tried using `case_when`, but I am not sure how to deliver coordinates to multiple columns. It is easy to do one column:

```
library(tidyverse)

# The numbers after the cities are the latitudes
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
   City1_lat = case_when(
    City1 == 'New York' ~ 40.7128,
    City1 == 'Boston' ~ 42.3601,
    City1 == 'Chicago' ~ 41.8781
  )
 )
```

How can I expand this to add in a `City1_lon` column? Trying to streamline this as much as possible, since I have several thousand rows of origins/destinations. Either a `dplyr` or `base` solution works. I would expand this for the destination cities, `City2`. For reference:

```
New York: 40.7128, 74.0060
Boston: 42.3601, 71.0589
Chicago: 41.8781, 87.6298
Cleveland: 41.4993, 81.6944
Atlanta: 33.7490, 84.3880
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df <- tibble(
  "City1" = c("New York", "Boston", "Chicago"),
  "City2" = c("Chicago", "Cleveland", "Atlanta"))


df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    City1_coords = case_when(
      City1 == 'New York' ~ list(c(40.7128,74.0060)),
      City1 == 'Boston' ~ list(c(42.3601,71.0589)),
      City1 == 'Chicago' ~ list(c(41.8781,87.6298))
    )
  ) %>% 
  mutate(City1_lat = City1_coords %>% map_dbl(~ .x[1] ),
         City1_lon = City1_coords %>% map_dbl(~ .x[2] ))
```

Comment: Did this, and got the following error: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: Result 125 is not a length 1 atomic vector.` Are my variables the wrong type? All I can think of. The example above works perfectly, but only on that example. Hmm

Comment: This was the issue with this answer: https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/337

Comment: Glad you figured it!

Answer (score 3):

With your city data in a dataframe like this:

```
> city
       City     lat    long
1  New York 40.7128 74.0060
2    Boston 42.3601 71.0589
3   Chicago 41.8781 87.6298
4 Cleveland 41.4993 81.6944
5   Atlanta 33.7490 84.3880
```

Use `match` to lookup city names across the tables, extract the lat-long, and renaming gives this:

```
> setNames(city[match(df$City1, city$City), c("lat","long")],c("City1lat","City1long"))
  City1lat City1long
1  40.7128   74.0060
2  42.3601   71.0589
3  41.8781   87.6298

> setNames(city[match(df$City2, city$City), c("lat","long")],c("City2lat","City2long"))
  City2lat City2long
3  41.8781   87.6298
4  41.4993   81.6944
5  33.7490   84.3880
```

which you can `cbind` onto your original data:

```
> df = cbind(df, setNames(city[match(df$City1, city$City), c("lat","long")],c("City1lat","City1long")), setNames(city[match(df$City2, city$City), c("lat","long")],c("City2lat","City2long")))
> df
     City1     City2 City1lat City1long City2lat City2long
1 New York   Chicago  40.7128   74.0060  41.8781   87.6298
2   Boston Cleveland  42.3601   71.0589  41.4993   81.6944
3  Chicago   Atlanta  41.8781   87.6298  33.7490   84.3880
```

Answer (score 3):

One option is to do a `left_join` after creating a 'keyval' dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
map_dfc(names(df), ~  df %>% 
                        select(.x) %>% 
                        left_join(keyval, by = setNames('City', .x))) %>%
    select(names(df), everything())  
# A tibble: 3 x 6
#  City1    City2       lat   lon  lat1  lon1
#  <chr>    <chr>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 New York Chicago    40.7  74.0  41.9  87.6
#2 Boston   Cleveland  42.4  71.1  41.5  81.7
#3 Chicago  Atlanta    41.9  87.6  33.7  84.4
```

---

If there are more columns in the original data and we are only interested in the 'City' columns, then only loop through the 'City' columns

```
df$journeys <- (100,200,300)
nm1 <- grep("City", names(df), value = TRUE)
map_dfc(nm1, ~  df %>% 
                     select(.x) %>% 
                     left_join(keyval, by = setNames('City', .x))) %>%  
      bind_cols(df %>% 
                  select(-one_of(nm1)))
```

#### data

```
keyval <- structure(list(City = c("New York", "Boston", "Chicago", "Cleveland", 
 "Atlanta"), lat = c(40.7128, 42.3601, 41.8781, 41.4993, 33.749
 ), lon = c(74.0068, 71.0589, 87.6298, 81.6944, 84.388)), row.names = c(NA, 
  -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Does the keyval set have to be length of the actual data set? I'm working with several thousand rows. So obviously a smaller set would be great

Comment: @papelr For ease of creation, the state names can be got from `state.name`

Comment: This seems to fail if there's other columns apart from City1 and City2 in the source data, eg if `df$journeys=c(100,200,300)`.

Comment: Yes, but robust is always better. I've not figured out how to make your code work only on two columns without first dropping all the other columns.

Comment: @Spacedman I guess the failing part is the last step `select(names(df)`, but i remove that and then append the other columns, should work fine

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it using `mutate_all` and `unnest`, with a bonus hack for naming the columns :

```
df %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(l = case_when(
      . == 'New York'  ~ list(tibble(at=40.7128, on=74.0060)),
      . == 'Boston'    ~ list(tibble(at=42.3601, on=71.0589)),
      . == 'Chicago'   ~ list(tibble(at=41.8781, on=87.6298)),
      . == 'Cleveland' ~ list(tibble(at=41.4993, on=81.6944)),
      . == 'Atlanta'   ~ list(tibble(at=33.7490, on=84.3880))
    )
  )) %>%
  unnest(.sep = "")

# # A tibble: 3 x 6
#      City1     City2 City1_lat City1_lon City2_lat City2_lon
#      <chr>     <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 New York   Chicago   40.7128   74.0060   41.8781   87.6298
# 2   Boston Cleveland   42.3601   71.0589   41.4993   81.6944
# 3  Chicago   Atlanta   41.8781   87.6298   33.7490   84.3880
```

This addresses *"Using case_when() to assign two new columns"*.

To solve the general problem I would recommend a solution based on left joins, as it is more flexible to have your keys and values in a neat separate table.

Comment: I think I'm blind. Where's the hack - but I like this solution a lot

Comment: `mutate_all` will create columns named `City1_l` and `City2_l`, then `unnest` , thanks to argument `sep=''` will create new columns by concatenating it with the tibble columns named `'at` and `on`. That's the hack :)

Comment: A more conventional way would have been to write `funs(gps = ...` and `tibble(lat=40.7128, lon=74.0060))` etc, then using `sep='_'` you would have yielded columns named `City1_gps_lat` etc

Comment: Ahhhhhh I see it

Answer (score 1):

You should call externally a file (in my example, called as data_xy) with info with "city, lat and long", then you can use left_join. Try this code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
data_xy <- tibble(city = c("New York", "Boston", "Chicago", "Cleveland", "Atlanta"),
                  lat = c(40.7128, 42.3601, 41.8781, 41.4993, 33.7490),
                  lon = c(74.0060, 71.0589, 87.6298, 81.6944, 84.3880))


df <- tibble("City1" = c("New York", "Boston", "Chicago"),
             "City2" = c("Chicago", "Cleveland", "Atlanta"))

df_latlon <- map(names(df), ~ left_join(df %>% select(.x),  data_xy, 
                                        by= structure(names = .x, .Data = "city")) )
df_latlon
```

The output:

```
> df_latlon
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  City1      lat   lon
  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 New York  40.7  74.0
2 Boston    42.4  71.1
3 Chicago   41.9  87.6

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  City2       lat   lon
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 Chicago    41.9  87.6
2 Cleveland  41.5  81.7
3 Atlanta    33.7  84.4
```